# Excel equation put answer in other cell? (without VBA)

Tags: excel

Is it possible, without using VBA to put answer from one cell into another?

For example:
(1) C1 =A1+B1 (equation in C1)
(2) I would like to extend the equation in C1 to put TRUE into D1, without putting an equation into D1 Cell.

I know this is a bit confusing and typically would put an equation in D1 cell, but, if possible, would like to try to avoid that.

Thanks.

Motivation: VBA might be blocked due to IA.  Desire to write also write information in Cell D1, along with the TRUE value placed in D1.

Edit with clarification:
If it is not possible, an answer of "It is not possible" or "Impossible" is acceptable.
Thanks again.

Comment: Please extend the question to include your reasoning. It looks like what you want to do is impossible, but what you want to achieve may well be possible.

Comment: Under what circumstances do you want TRUE to appear in D1?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In general, as the other answers argue, it is not possible.

However, If what you want is `D1` being `TRUE` or `FALSE` based on some condition, then there is a way to do it.

Suppose we want to get the result of the formula `=A1=B1+C1` in `D1` without using a formula. Therefore, `D1` should show `TRUE` whenever `A1=B1+C1` and `FALSE` whenever `A1<>B1+C1`.

- Place the cursor on `D1`. Enter the value 0.
- Go to `Conditional Formatting-->New Rule` and enter `=A1=B1+C1` as a rule.
- Click on the `Format` box, go to `Number-->Custom` and under `Type:` write `#,##0.00;-#,##0.00;"TRUE"`
- Click OK on all the boxes.

Then repeat the above procedure but enter as formula `=IFERROR(A1<>B1+C1,TRUE)` as a rule and write `"FALSE"` instead of `"TRUE"` under the custom type.

`D1` writes `TRUE` whenever `A1=B1+C1` and `FALSE` whenever `A1<>B1+C1`.

Obviously, this procedure can be repeated regardless of the actual formula (as long as it can be entered in conditional formatting), under the assumption that the result of the formula can be `TRUE` or `FALSE`.

I hope this helps!

Answer (score 0):

Seems odd for me to do something like this and I do not understand why you cannot use VBA which is an obvious solution. You would need to provide more details on what you want to achieve.

The only automation to carry such a task, according to my knowledge, would be to add a PivotChart so that its value is in cell D1. You would however have to anyway refresh the PivotTable manually w/o using VBA.

Answer (score 0):

A formula cannot alter another cell, it can only cause a change to the cell it is in.

This also applies to a *UDF* which is a formula with vba behind it.

The only way to make the change would be to use the vba event for the change of cells, and check to see if a cell in *C* has changed, and then alter *D* appropriately.